# How do you lock your screen from AwesomeWM in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: awesome

I can't figure out how to lock my screen from AwesomeWM in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

How is this done?

I tried running `slock` as suggested in the other question suggested below and I have to restart my computer to get back in after locking it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to lock session from awesome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421705/how-to-lock-session-from-awesome)

Comment: I tried that, when I run `slock` I have to reboot my machine to get back in...

Comment: The screen turns red and I can't get back into my session.

Comment: Can you get back into your session after locking it with `slock` without rebooting like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/917320/switching-between-console-and-gui/917386#917386? You also need to select awesome from the login screen with this method.

Comment: @karel I tried it, but it didn't work....https://askubuntu.com/a/917386/3756 I believe that's for Ubuntu 17.10, I've got 16.04 LTS

Comment: Actually it's for 16.04 too if you read the 16.04 part at the end, but if it didn't work that probably wouldn't work either.